# Remove characters from the result

Tags: php, arrays, string

How to remove characters from the result.
When I try to delete characters I have error

Code:

```
function getInbetweenStrings($start, $end, $str){
$regex = "/$start([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$end/";
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
return $matches[1];
}
$text ='<input type="hidden" name="elementId" value="1826" id="elementId">';
$str = $text;
$str_arr = getInbetweenStrings('<input type="hidden" name="elementId" value="', '" id="elementId">', $str);
print_r($str_arr);
```

The result of this code looks like this

```
Array ( [0] => 1826 )
```

I just want 1826
and when I change `print_r($str_arr);` to echo `$str_arr;` then the code writes me just Array not even `Array ( [0] => 1826 )`.

Do you have any advice on the code.

Comment: You can `echo` the array value like this `echo $str_arr[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$str_arr` is an array and you cannot echo it. The array contains elements, you can echo them if they are not arrays.

Simply do this:

```
echo $str_arr[0];
```

or you can assign it to a variable:

```
$your_var = $str_arr[0];
echo $your_var;
```

Your code triggering on a form submit:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    function getInbetweenStrings($start, $end, $str){
    $regex = "/$start([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$end/";
    preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
    }
    $text ='<input type="hidden" name="elementId" value="1826" id="elementId">';
    $str = $text;
    $str_arr = getInbetweenStrings('<input type="hidden" name="elementId" value="', '" id="elementId">', $str);
    //print_r($str_arr);
    $var = $str_arr[0];
    echo $var;
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" value="Click the button" name="submitted" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to get the html code from website and then get value from one line of code, and this code I want run when I press button.
Code to read website html I have and now code to read value I have so now I want just button.

Comment: You are incredible
Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`$str_arr` is an array of the format `print_r()` spits out.

So doing `echo $str_arr[0];` will give you your `1826`.